# Interfaces, classes and constructors in java

Tags: java, class, interface, constructor

Here's something that bothers me regarding Interfaces and classes.

I'm trying to do an implemataion for an interface called IPAddress by a class named IPAddressString.
Ipadress contains four parts.

I'm writing a method named mask which mask the current address with the given one. The masking 
operation is a bitwise 'and' operation on all four parts of the address. You get all the four parts by a method that I wrote named getOctet. (you can see below).

Ok, so I need to mask my this.IpAdress which with it I wrote my class with a new general IPAddress.

While writing the mask I face a problem. I calculated 4 integers that with them I want to return a new IPAddress type. In order to do that I need to use my constructer which returns 
IPAddressString type, and obivously I cannot convert from IPAddressString to IPAddress.

I'm lost. what should I do? why Isn't my constructure is no good for this? Isn't IPAddressString a sub-type of IPAddress?

Here's the code which will make it simpler:

Here's the Interface:

```
public interface IPAddress {

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the IP address, e.g. "192.168.0.1"
     */
    public String toString();

    /**
     * Compares this IPAddress to the specified object
     * 
     * @param other
     *            the IPAddress to compare this string against
     * @return <code>true</code> if both IPAddress objects represent the same IP
     *         address, <code>false</code> otherwise.
     */
    public boolean equals(IPAddress other);

    /**
     * Returns one of the four parts of the IP address. The parts are indexed
     * from left to right. For example, in the IP address 192.168.0.1 part 0 is
     * 192, part 1 is 168, part 2 is 0 and part 3 is 1.
     * 
     * @param index
     *            The index of the IP address part (0, 1, 2 or 3)
     * @return The value of the specified part.
     */
    public int getOctet(int index);

    /**
     * Returns whether this address is a private network address. There are
     * three ranges of addresses reserved for 'private networks' 10.0.0.0 -
     * 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 and 192.168.0.0 -
     * 192.168.255.255
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> if this address is in one of the private
     *         network address ranges, <code>false</code> otherwise.
     * @see <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Private_networks">Private Networks</a>
     */
    public boolean isPrivateNetwork();

    /**
     * Mask the current address with the given one. The masking operation is a
     * bitwise 'and' operation on all four parts of the address.
     * 
     * @param mask
     *            the IP address with which to mask
     * @return A new IP address representing the result of the mask operation.
     *         The current address is not modified.
     */
    public IPAddress mask(IPAddress mask);
}
```

Here's my class:

```
public class IPAddressString {

    private String IpAdress;

    public IPAddressString(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4) {
        this.IpAdress = num1 + "." + num2 + "." + num3 + "." + num4;

    }


    public String toString() {
        return this.IpAdress;

    }

    public boolean equals(IPAddress other) {
        return ((other.toString()).equals(IpAdress));
    }

    public int getOctet(int index) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int point = index;
        int countPoints = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= IpAdress.length() - 1; i++) {
            if ((IpAdress.charAt(i)) == '.') {
                countPoints++;

            }
            if ((countPoints == point) && IpAdress.charAt(i) != '.') {
                buf.append(IpAdress.charAt(i));
            }

        }
        String result = buf.toString();
        return Integer.parseInt(result);
    }

    public boolean isPrivateNetwork() {

        if (getOctet(0) == 10) {
            return true;
        }

        if (getOctet(0) == 172) {
            if (getOctet(1) >= 16 && getOctet(1) <= 31) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (getOctet(0) == 192) {
            if (getOctet(1) == 168) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }


    public IPAddress mask(IPAddress mask){
        int n0= mask.getOctet(0) & getOctet(0);
        int n1= mask.getOctet(1) & getOctet(1);
        int n2=mask.getOctet(2) & getOctet(2);
        int n3=mask.getOctet(3) & getOctet(3);



         IPAddress n1= new IPAddressString (n0,n1,n2,n3);
    }

}
```

The problem again is with the method mask. I need to return a new IPAddress, but I should use my constructure. what am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: `IPAddressString` needs to *implement* `IPAddress`

Comment: Have you tried implementing IPAddress?

Comment: @Tedil: yeah, Did I write the opposite?

Comment: You did not implement at all.

Comment: @RedSoxFan: I don't understand. I implement IPAddress methods with IPAddressString.

Comment: @Nir Refer to Swaranga Sarma's answer

Comment: And please remove toString() and equals() from your interface!  toString is inherited from Object anyway, so it should never be declared in an interface.  Your equals has a different signature than the one in Object and will cause confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `IPAddress` in `IPAddressString`. Although you are implementing all the methods of `IPAddress` interface in your `IPAddressString` class, you are not telling this to the compiler [which clearly cannot guess your intentions].

change the definition of your class to :

```
class IPAddressString implements IPAddress
```

This should solve the problem in conversion.

Now this line:

```
IPAddress n1= new IPAddressString (n0,n1,n2,n3);
```

will not give you problems since the hierarchy is established. And you can peacefully return `n1`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple public class IPAddressString implements IPAddress will solve the problem.

Another suggestion that jumped to my eye:

It doesn't make any sense to declare the equals and toString() method in the interface because every object already has them. You wouldn't get a compile error if you didn't implement it.

Furthermore, the equals method must always have the signature boolean equals(**Object** other), because only then it overrides the method of Object and will be called correctly at all time.