# one more question about Interfaces, classes and constructors in java

Tags: java, interface

One more question that relates to [this interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587430/interfaces-classes-and-constructors-in-java).

Let's say that I would like to implement the interface now with arrays.

Here's a part of my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class IPAddressShortArray implements IPAddress {

private int [] IpAdress;

public  IPAddressShortArray(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4) {
    this.IpAdress[0] =num1 ;
    this.IpAdress[1]=num2;
    this.IpAdress[2]=num3;
    this.IpAdress[3]=num4;

}

public String toString() {
    return IpAdress.toString();

}

public boolean equals(IPAddress other) {

    boolean T= true;
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        if (this.IpAdress[i]!=other[i]){
            .......

        }
    }
}
```

There's a compiler error saying that `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to IPAddress`, but IpAddress right now is represented by array, so what's the problem? why can't I refer to `other[i]` if I have this implementation?

I know that equals should not be implemented again. Let's assume that I want to implement it.

Comment: `IpAdress` (a member variable) and `IPAddress` (an interface). Extremely confusing, and also incorrect style (variables should start in lower case).

Comment: Yeah, I would name that private array `ipAddressOctets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of interfaces is that they hide implementation details.  You're using a variable that is declared as of type `IPAddress` but then trying to use it as an `IPAddressShortArray`.

A proper implementation would be to add a method to the interface to get each octet of the address, e.g.:

```
public int getOctet(int octetIndex)
```

In the `IPAddressShortArray` class the implementation of this method would look like:

```
public int getOctet(int octetindex) {
  return this.IpAddress[octetindex];
}
```

Then in your `equals` method you would use `other.getOctet(i)` instead of `other[i]` or `other.IpAddress[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

`other` is still an IPAddress, not an array.  Also, you're never initializing the IpAdress member (you need `new int[4]`), and you spelled it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Other is type `IPAddress` which isn't an array. I'd find the code easier to use if `IpAddress` started with a lower case character as that is a very common convention for Java variables, classes generally start with a capital.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (this.IpAdress[i]!=other[i]){
```

`other` is of type `IPAddress`, so you can't treat it like an array.

Did you mean

```
 if (this.IpAdress[i]!=other.IpAdress[i]){
```

?

Comment: There's a compiler error saying:
pAdress cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: You forgot to press the `I` key on your keyboard?

Comment: Also, if it's a private member, add a public accessor.

Comment: no, it says IpAdress cannot be resolved or is not a field, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I realized that `other` is an `IPAddress`, not a `IPAddressShortArray`, so why would it contain an array? If you want an `IPAddressShortArray`, you need to take that as a parameter for your function, i.e. `public boolean equals(IPAddressShortArray other)`.