# Understanding Interfaces, classes and constructors in java

Tags: java, class, interface

Right now I'm trying to implement [this interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587430/interfaces-classes-and-constructors-in-java) with an int which represents a binary number.

I know I shouldn't implement`to string();` , but Let's assume that I need to.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
public class IPAddressInt implements IPAddress {
private int ipAdress;

public IPAddressInt(int num1,int num2, int num3, int num4){
    String n1=Integer.toBinaryString(num1);
    String n2=Integer.toBinaryString(num2);
    String n3=Integer.toBinaryString(num3);
    String n4=Integer.toBinaryString(num4);
    
    String finalString=n1+n2+n3+n4;
    this.ipAdress=Integer.parseInt(finalString);
}

public String toString() {
    return this.toString();
    
    
}
```

when I'm tring to return `this.ipAdress.toString();` or even  `ipAdress.toString()`
the compiler says that it `Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int`,
and when I write only  `this.toString();` it works. why? I know that an int can be converted to a string, and how come the `this` works and the whole statement is not? shouldn't  it be the same? will I get what I want anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: Glad to see you have both a sense of humor & common sense.  :-) Hope you get a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `this.toString()` is just going to blow up - it's calling the same method recursively, with no exit.

The reason you can't call `toString` directly on `ipAddress` is that `int` is a primitive type, and you can't call methods on primitive types.

To convert anything to a string, use `String.valueOf(ipAddress)`. For `int` in particular, you could use `Integer.toString(ipAddress)`.

It's not really clear why you're doing the conversion to a binary string in the first place though... that doesn't look like a good idea to me. Any reason why you're not using

```
ipAddress = (num1 << 24) | (num2 << 16) | (num3 << 8) | num4;
```

(assuming each value is really in the range 0-255).

I *highly* doubt that the binary representation is really want you want, particularly given the lack of padding, and that you're then trying to parse it as a *decimal* number.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you for the comment.
Can you explain what you did creating this kind of ipAddress?

Is it wrong to implement it my way? I guess It won't be the whole number since the left zeros won't appear, right?

Comment: @Nir: It's not clear what you mean. In general, it's almost never a good idea to convert one numeric form (in this case 4 separate integers) into another numeric form (in this case 1 integer) by using string conversions.

Comment: @Jon: I'd like to understand what this expression: `ipAddress = (num1 << 24) | (num2 << 16) | (num3 << 8) | num4;` means.

Using this bitwise operator, you get the numbers converted automatically to a binary representation?

Comment: @Nir: Numbers are already stored in binary. I assumed that you were going to pass in something like 192, 168, 0, 1 to represent the IP address "192.168.0.1". The left shifts and ORs will create a single 32-bit representation of the four 8-bit values.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you. how can I work with this kind of representation?
Let's say that I want to now locate the third original number, how can I do that? I tried to read in wikipedia, but this representation is Poorly coverd.

Comment: @Nir: You'd need to use bitmasking and shifting. This is moving quite a long way away from the original question though, and isn't particularly simple to answer in comments. I suggest you ask a separate question - after investigating it more yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it works" I suspect you mean "it compiles". If you actually call that `toString` method you'll get a stack overflow, or maybe just an infinite loop if your compiler/JVM is very clever.

To convert an `int` to a string, call `Integer.toString(this.ipAdress)`. (But preferably spell `address` correctly :-).)

[EDITED to add: after writing this I see that in another answer Jon Skeet prefers `String.valueOf` rather than `Integer.toString` for this purpose. He's a very smart chap and probably has a good reason. It'll mean less has to change if you change the type of `ipAddress` -- er, I mean `ipAdress`, for instance.]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably to implement the toString method like this:

```
public String toString()
{
    return Integer.toString(ipAdress);
}
```

What the compiler says is true because you cannot invoke ANY methods on primitive types. You have to wrap the primitive int into an Integer which has the method toString implemented. The code snippet above is just a more effective way of calling:

```
return Integer.valueOf(ipAdress).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toString method is recursively calling itself and will end up in a stack overflow exception.

Try converting ipAdress to a String like this:

public String toString() {
  return Integer.toString(ipAdress);
}

FYI, your variable ipAdress has a typo, should be ipAddress.